# Python module: use during setup but not to be installed

Tags: python, setuptools

How can I specify to Setuptools that a module should be available during setup, but not installed for run-time?

I have made an extension command used by my Python distribution (in this case it auto-generates version metadata), and the module is included in the project tree.

```
foo-project/
    setup.py
    MANIFEST.in
    foo/
        __init__.py
        bar.py
    version_info.py
```

To run Setuptools commands (such as `egg_info` or `develop`), the `version_info` module is imported by `setup`. So that file `version_info.py` needs to be part of the source distribution.

But putting that file in the source distribution also (by default?) automatically includes it in any binary distribution, such as `bdist_wheel` or `bdist_dumb`. That's wrong, because the file isn't needed at run-time and should not be installed.

How can I specify that the file is a Python module needed in the source distribution for setup commands, but not to be installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include *source distribution files* in the [`MANIFEST.in` file](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute); these files are included when building a source distribution that includes the `setup.py` file.

Do not include the file in `data_files` or `package_data` or `py_modules` and it won't be included in the binary distribution (just like `setup.py` won't be).